# How to send a simple Firebase push notification to everyone from the client?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been doing so much research, but it seems like all the articles out there are either sending notifications from the console or sending a push notification to a single device.

All I want is to send a push notification using Firebase ON my client and **not on the Console** to **everyone**. Do I need a server? If so, what information do I need to retrieve from it?

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen that's using the deprecated API

Comment: No API used in that blog post is deprecated as far as I know. Which part do you mean? For an even more up to date sample, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens. But I updated the blog post to point there too.

Comment: And plus, that covers the sending of push notifications to a single device.

Comment: To use the firebase new way and to send to a user segment, try [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience). If you want to send to a topic, try [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-topics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to send a downstream message, you don't really need a server. You can simply [use Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309674/fcm-with-postman-the-request-was-missing-an-authentication-key-fcm-token/45310143#45310143) or [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664911/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-click-action/44665817#44665817). Just specify the registration token(s)/topic you want to send your message payload to.

If you are aiming to send the downstream message from the client (Android app) itself, I would strongly advise not to. Quoting a portion of @FrankvanPuffelen's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42838376/4625829):

> Sending a message to devices (so-called downstream messages) requires a HTTP call that specifies the *server key*. As its name implies, this key should only be used in environments you can trust.

It is to avoid exposing the key to unauthorized users, preventing exploitation.

Comment: You can use  for sending a message to devices (so-called downstream messages) HTTPS call that specifies the server key.

Comment: I won't worry about security, since this app won't be public. Can you provide me with the way?

Comment: So just for practice? I guess you can look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41560266/4625829) for reference.

Comment: Hi @AbAppletic If you think that my post contains the details that answered what you need, please do mark it as accepted, so that your question will be marked as *Already Answered*. Doing the same for your other posts would really help. Cheers! :)

Comment: @AbAppletic Of course i can. Watch my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging/41913555#41913555